# How to make antd modal have rounded corners

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

```
  <Modal
    title=""
    visible={isModalVisible}
    onOk={handleOk}
    onCancel={handleCancel}
    cancelButtonProps={{ style: { display: "none" } }}
  >
    <img src="./test.svg" alt="" style={{ marginLeft: "8.5rem" }} />
    <p>It has been added!</p>
  </Modal>
```

I tried added style to the Modal,

```
style ={{borderRadius:"20px",overflow:"auto"}}
```

But that made on the top corners rounded and cutting off the bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just overrider `.ant-modal-content` style in css/sass/scss file

```css
/*your selectors if needed*/
.ant-modal-content {
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* background: red; */
}
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-qqe5k?file=/index.css:27-127

Comment: when we add the title top corners are not rounded. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite both `.ant-modal` and `.ant-modal-content` following way:

```
.ant-modal {
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* Only border-radius here */
}

.ant-modal-content {
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* border: 10px solid black; */
}
```

That way you get both corners rounded

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the style:

```
.ant-modal-content {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

only the bottom corners will get rounded. So you also need to target the top corners using ".ant-modal-header". Here's the full styling:

```
.ant-modal-content,.ant-modal-header {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Now all the corners should be rounded